# OrmLite execute sql statement

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I have a database in `OrmLite`.
Here one of the tables — `Field`:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Field {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private long id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String type;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    private Collection<FieldListValue> listValue;
    ...
}
```

I want to delete some values from the table like in this way:

```
List<Field> fields = fieldDao.queryForAll();
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (field.getType().equals("list") && field.getListValue().size() == 0) {
        fieldDao.delete(field);
    }
}
```

But how can I execute this query with `DeleteBuilder` ?

The problem with this piece of code `...(SELECT COUNT(listValue) FROM Field) = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how can I execute this query with DeleteBuilder ?

There is not a direct way that you can use the `DeleteBuilder` to do this because the foreign objects actually have no information in the `Field` class.

However, here's one way you can accomplish this using a raw-query and then the `DeleteBuilder`.

In approximate code:

```
qb = fieldListValueDao.queryBuilder();
// raw query for the field_ids in the fieldListValue table
rawResults = qb.queryRaw("SELECT field_id FROM fieldListValue GROUP BY field_id",
    new RawRowMapper<Integer>() {
        // each result row is a single integer in the 0th column
        public Integer mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] resultColumns) {
            return Integer.parseInt(resultColumns[0]);
        }
    });
```

For help on the raw queries see: http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries

Once you have the raw-results of the `field_id` values, you can then do:

```
deleteBuilder = fieldDao.deleteBuilder();
// delete any rows that are not in the raw-results -- who have no fieldListValue entries
deleteBuilder.where().notIn("id", rawResults);
deleteBuilder.delete();
```

You also might be able to do it with the `notIn("id", queryBuilder)` method:

```
qb = fieldListValueDao.queryBuilder();
qb.selectColumns("field_id");
qb.groupBy("field_id");
...
deleteBuilder = fieldDao.deleteBuilder();
deleteBuilder.where().notIn("id", qb);
deleteBuilder.delete();
```

I would need to check this to make sure however.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
//get instance of DeleteBuilder
DeleteBuilder<Field, Integer> deleteBuilder = fieldDao.deleteBuilder();
//construct yours WHERE
//in this exampe we select fields with "id"=0
deleteBuilder.where().eq("id", 0);
//call delete
deleteBuilder.delete();
```

If you want to delete rows, that you want after yours codes conditions you can form an ArrayList of objects to delete and then pass their ids to deleteBuilder where statement like so

```
List<Integer> ids= new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Field> fields = fieldDao.queryForAll();
List<Field> fieldsToDelete = new ArrayList<Field>();
for (Field field : fields) 
{
    if (field.getType().equals("list") && field.getListValue().size() == 0)
    {
        ids.add(field.getId);
        fieldsToDelete.add(field);
    }
}
fieldDao.delete(ids);
//or
fieldDao.delete(fieldsToDelete);
//or
//get instance of DeleteBuilder
DeleteBuilder<Field, Integer> deleteBuilder = fieldDao.deleteBuilder();
//construct yours WHERE
//in this exampe we select fields with "id"=0
deleteBuilder.where().in("id", ids);
//call delete
deleteBuilder.delete();
```

Comment: Looks not very concisely)

Comment: See updated answer. Anyway you should form a Collection of objects (or their ids) to delete.